# View Statement returning duplicate columns..why?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query...

The reason it will fail is because the select statement returns two columns named VendorID...However...I don't understand why.

```
CREATE VIEW Example4 AS
    SELECT *
    FROM invoices JOIN
         Vendors
         on Invoices.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
    WHERE InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal > 0;
```

`

Comment: `SELECT *` returns columns from both tables (Invoices and Vendors).  I assume there are columns with the same name in both tables.

Comment: You are using `select *` and asking why you are getting duplicate column names.  The reason seems obvious.  Just choose the columns you really want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT *` returns columns from both tables (Invoices and Vendors).  Change your query to select only the columns you want.

```
SELECT Invoices.Colx, Vendors.Coly
FROM invoices JOIN
     Vendors
     on Invoices.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
WHERE InvoiceTotal - PaymentTotal - CreditTotal > 0;
```

Comment: Newbie question...I thought SELECT * was only pulling everything  FROM the invoices table...how did it pull everyting from both? Was that due to the join?

Comment: When you SELECT * and there is a join it will pull all columns from all tables.  You can do `SELECT Invoices.*` if you want otherwise it doesn't know which table(s) to pull the columns from.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and clarification!